# Does listening to Hanuman Chalisa every day give the same benefits as chanting the Hanuman Chalisa?

Tags: karma, hanuman, bhakti, prayer, vedic-chanting

Does listening to Hanuman Chalisa every day give the same benefits as chanting the Hanuman Chalisa?

Comment: How are Gayatri mantra and Hanuman Chalisa same? Our policy for closing duplicates is based on questions. Not answers. Gayatri mantra has many restrictions. Hanuman Chalisa doesn't have any. They are not same.

Comment: It can if you progress the sravana (listening) to manana and dhyasa of hanuman. Same with chanting.